# try? returns double optional in Swift 4

Tags: exception, try-catch, swift4, swift-optionals

There are a lot of similar questions but no one describes how to handle exceptions with `try?` + double optional.

I know str1 doesn't generate exception. It is just an example:

```
let str1: String? = "some string"
let str2: String? = try? str1 //compilation error because "try? str1" returns object of type String??
```

One of the possible solutions is replace `try?` -> `try`:

```
let str1: String? = "some string"
let str2: String? = {
    do {
        return try str1
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}()
```

But is it possible to preserve `try?` like the following?

`let str2: String? = try? ...//do something with str1 in the same single line`

P.S. In Swift 5 the initial code works but I need to something with it in Swift 4 (upgrading to Swift 5 requires significant changes in project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a double optional was the default behavior since Error Handling with `do - try - catch` was introduced in Swift 3.

In Swift 5 [SE 230: Flatten nested optionals resulting from 'try?'](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0230-flatten-optional-try.md) has been implemented.

> upgrading to Swift 5 requires significant changes in project

Do it, it's worth it. The changes are less dramatic than from Swift 2 to 3